# O que é curl/curl_setopt

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou fazendo uma integração com MailChimp, e me deparei com este código:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));
```

Queria saber o que é curl, `curl_setopt` etc., e para que servem (em um conceito geral, e não apenas do código apresentado).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) é uma ferramenta para criar requisições em diversos protocolos (incluindo HTTP, HTTPS e FTP, entre muitos outros) e obter conteúdo remoto. Ele existe como ferramenta de linha de comando, e também como biblioteca, a `libcurl`, que o PHP incorpora e expõe por meio das funções `curl_*`.

O código que você mostrou gera uma requisição HTTP com o método POST para o URL em `$submit_url`, e o conteúdo postado será o da variável `$payload`. A função [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) define todos os parâmetros da requisição. Como o parâmetro `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` foi definido como `true`, a função [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) (que dispara a requisição) irá retornar o conteúdo recuperado do URL.